# PHP echo line X times different text

Tags: php, image, repeat

Title might not make complete sense, couldn't think of a way to explain it so I will do a mock PHP example.

```
<?php
$startNumber = 1;
$endNumber = 15;
$fileExt = '.jpg';
?>
```

And then on the page it will echo from the $startNumber to the $endNumber in something like a foreach

```
<?php echo("<img src=\"#.jpg\">"); ?>
```

Hope this is making sense...

I'd also like to point out that the numbers < 10 start with a 0 so it will need to be in the image source link.

Comment: Sidenote: `$startNumber = 01;` - 01 stands at being treated as an octal. Either set it inside quotes, or use `$startNumber = 1;` - Edit: Which you've done in an edit ;)

Comment: Is there something here that a simple `for` loop cannot handle?

Comment: Do you mean numbers should be between 0 and 10 ?

Comment: Simple `for` loop: `for($i = $startNumber; $i <= $endNumber; $i++) { echo "<img src=\"{$i}{$fileExt}\">"; }`

Comment: @Jon No idea, I had it in JavaScript, but that made styling it how I wanted difficult so I'm going over to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` is not a function, it's a language construct. Don't use ().

Also you need to use a loop like for() to do that (Also see sidenote of Fred -ii).

```
$endNumber = 15;
for($i = 1; $i <= $endNumber; $i++) {
    if($i < 10) {
        $i = "0".$i;
    }
    echo "<img src=\"".$i.".jpg\" />";
}
```

If this is not what you asked, add more information.